# symfony 2.3 app.php seems not using the same twig as app_dev.php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I'm facing a strange problem with symfony 2.3

If I load pages using app_dev.php I can see my custom twig, but if I use app.php it seems to use an empty twig

please take a look at

http://www.waltervalvoenterprise.com/app_dev.php/login

and

http://www.waltervalvoenterprise.com/app.php/login

As you can see in source code, with app.php it doesn't load bootstrap etc so I think that it uses another twig...

Have you ever seen something like this? do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this just occur on your login page or on all pages in the `prod` environment? Did you warm up your cache etc?

Comment: I've got this error on  all pages... I've cleaned cache,but nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try this commands and see if something changes.

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console assets:install --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug
```

Because you have a login area I guess you configured your `security.yml`? If so don't secure your assets behind a firewall. Otherwise they don't load.
Could be that the `dev` assets are cached so you haven't noticed it yet. But that's only a suggestion...

In your firewalls section try the following:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:    ^/(_profiler|_wdt|images|css|js)
        security:   false
```

Comment: wonderful! thanks! it's strange, but somehow cache folder became unwritable

Answer (score 0):

Nothing with Twig here. You are using assets and in production environment you need to dump it first. Read more about [dumping assetic files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files).

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

Check your page with google chrome console and you will see the errors

```
GET http://www.waltervalvoenterprise.com/js/5a7d0d0.js 404 (Not Found) login:41
GET http://www.waltervalvoenterprise.com/css/4e1390a.css 404 (Not Found) login:8
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion. unfortunately doesn't work, this command gives me this error : MYFOLDERS/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/views" directory does not exist.